# t-sql transpose column into row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables here:

- `Property` table.
- `PropertyAudit` - capture one or more changes made in "Property" table.
- `PStatus` - which is a lookup table for StautsID column.

Here is what I have so far.

This is the tables script and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Property 
(
     PropertyID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,StatusID INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,Country VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
    ,Town VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,LastChangedBy VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,LastChanged VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Property (
    PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,Country
    ,Town
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    73555
    ,1
    ,'NoMansLand'
    ,'BEEREN'
    ,'Agent009'
    ,'2020-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO Property (
    PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,Country
    ,Town
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    72896
    ,6
    ,'Neverlands'
    ,'RIDDERK'
    ,'Agent007'
    ,'2020-08-10 08:41:22.447'
    );
    
CREATE TABLE PropertyAudit 
(
    AID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,PropertyID INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,StatusID INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,LastChangedBy VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,LastChanged VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO PropertyAudit (
    AID
    ,PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    12340
    ,73555
    ,7
    ,'Agent009'
    ,'2020-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO PropertyAudit (
    AID
    ,PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    12341
    ,73555
    ,6
    ,'Agent007'
    ,'2020-08-24 08:10:53.223'
    );

INSERT INTO PropertyAudit (
    AID
    ,PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    12342
    ,73555
    ,5
    ,'Agent009'
    ,'2020-02-13 14:38:10.913'
    );

INSERT INTO PropertyAudit (
    AID
    ,PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    12343
    ,73555
    ,3
    ,'Agent009'
    ,'2020-02-13 14:33:25.967'
    );

INSERT INTO PropertyAudit (
    AID
    ,PropertyID
    ,StatusID
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    12344
    ,73555
    ,2
    ,'Agent009'
    ,'2020-02-10 13:37:57.527'
    );

CREATE TABLE PStatus 
(
     ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,StatusName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,LastChangedBy VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,LastChanged VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,'REJECTED'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-05-28 17:02:42.977'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    2
    ,'NEW Contract'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-05-28 17:02:42.977'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    3
    ,'ACTIVE Contract'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    4
    ,'MONITOR'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    5
    ,'DEAL'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    6
    ,'DEALT'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    7
    ,'COMPLETED'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );

INSERT INTO PStatus (
    ID
    ,StatusName
    ,LastChangedBy
    ,LastChanged
    )
VALUES (
    8
    ,'ABORTED'
    ,'dbo'
    ,'2013-10-15 12:41:14.280'
    );
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

Final output:

```
+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| PRD Ref | Latest_Status | Opening_Status | ChangedBy |        ChangedOn        |
+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
|   73555 | COMPLETED     | NEW CONTRACT   | Agent009  | 2020-10-15 12:41:14.280 |
+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Here is what I have tried.

How do I introduce 2 columns "Lastest_Status" and "Opening_Status" and copy the values from the Status column.

```
SELECT prop.[PropertyID] AS "PRD Ref"
    ,(
        SELECT [StatusName]
        FROM [PStatus]
        WHERE pa.StatusID = [ID]
        ) AS "Status"
    ,pa.[LastChangedBy] AS "ChangedBy"
    ,pa.[LastChanged] AS "ChangedOn"
FROM [PropertyAudit] pa
INNER JOIN [Property] prop ON pa.PropertyID = prop.PropertyID
WHERE pa.PropertyID = 73555
ORDER BY pa.PropertyID DESC
```

```sql
+---------+-----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| PRD Ref |     Status      | ChangedBy |        ChangedOn        |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
|   73555 | COMPLETED       | Agent009  | 2020-10-15 12:41:14.280 |
|   73555 | DEALT           | Agent007  | 2020-08-24 08:10:53.223 |
|   73555 | DEAL            | Agent009  | 2020-02-13 14:38:10.913 |
|   73555 | ACTIVE Contract | Agent009  | 2020-02-13 14:33:25.967 |
|   73555 | NEW Contract    | Agent009  | 2020-02-10 13:37:57.527 |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select p.propertyid, 
    max(case when pa.rn_desc = 1 then s.statusname end) last_status,
    max(case when pa.rn_asc  = 1 then s.statusname end) opening_status,
    p.lastchangedby,
    p.lastchanged
from property p
inner join (
    select pa.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by propertyid order by lastchanged) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by propertyid order by lastchanged desc) rn_desc
    from propertyaudit pa
) pa on pa.propertyid = p.propertyid
inner join pstatus s on s.id = pa.statusid
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
group by p.propertyid, p.lastchangedby, p.lastchanged
```

Note that you don't really need table `property` to get the result that you want. We can dig further into the audit table, like so:

```
select pa.propertyid, 
    max(case when pa.rn_desc = 1 then s.statusname     end) last_status,
    max(case when pa.rn_asc  = 1 then s.statusname     end) opening_status,
    max(case when pa.rn_desc = 1 then pa.lastchangedby end) lastchangedby,
    max(case when pa.rn_desc = 1 then pa.lastchanged   end) lastchanged
from (
    select pa.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by propertyid order by lastchanged) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by propertyid order by lastchanged desc) rn_desc
    from propertyaudit pa
) pa
inner join pstatus s on s.id = pa.statusid
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
group by pa.propertyid
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bf9d0c24ff0544938c881b4f140ea09)** - both queries yield:

```
propertyid | last_status | opening_status | lastchangedby | lastchanged            
---------: | :---------- | :------------- | :------------ | :----------------------
     73555 | COMPLETED   | NEW Contract   | Agent009      | 2020-10-15 12:41:14.280
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for the swift reply. i used the 1st approach, since i will be pulling other columns from property. kudos to you....

Comment: quick question. where can i add an Index column to sequentially order. if that makes sense. i tried to add below line right at the beginning  but it starts to break. `,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PropertyID ORDER BY statusname DESC) AS "INDEX"` if possible.